# javascript redirect on valid submit

Tags: javascript

I have a forum that calls a few functions on submit. The javascript looks like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x=document.forms["checkout"]["fname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
    var x=document.forms["checkout"]["lname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("Last name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
    var x=document.forms["checkout"]["address"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("Address must be filled out");
    return false;
    }   
    var x=document.forms["checkout"]["email"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("Email address must be filled out");
    return false;
    }   
    var x=document.forms["checkout"]["phone"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("Phone number must be filled out");
    return false;
    }   
    var x=document.forms["checkout"]["card"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert("Credit card info must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
}
 function validateEmail(email) {
     var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@@\[?((25[0-    5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.)   {2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(email);
 }
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var ppattern = new RegExp(/^[\d ]+$/);
    return ppattern.test(phone);
}
function validateCard(card) {
    var cpattern = new RegExp(/(?:\d[ ]?){12,17}\d/);
    return cpattern.test(card);
}
```

How can I write it out such that on valid forum submission(after checking that all the javascript functions are valid) that it redirects to a conformation page?

Comment: Check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validation() {

    // validation stuff here

    if (validated) { redirect('url here'); }
}

function redirect(url) {

    window.location.href = url;

}
```